# Remove Fragments and Reload with Refresh Button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, refresh

I have three `Fragments` in a `FragmentActivity` (with `viewPager`).  I want to add a refresh button that basically drops all Fragments and reloads as new.  Each `Fragment` has  `ListView`.  Is this an improper hack or should I just refresh the `ListViews`?  (If so, I am not sure how to access the `ListViews` in the `Fragments` from `FragmentActivity`?)

Here is how I set up Fragments:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

            mViewPager
                    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                        }
                    });

            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, your FragmentActivity should be able to access each of the three Fragments correct? Then set up a static method which refreshes the list (re attach the adapter) in each of those Fragments and have a method in FragmentActivity call those three methods when your refresh button is pressed.

Comment: Edit:  I see what you mean now, ok.. will let you know.

Comment: I see how your answer is the solution.  But my `adapter` is set inside an `AsyncTask` where I grab list data from `MySQL` database.  So I was trying to get the refresh button to simply resetting the `ArrayList`s associated with the `ListView` back to empty, and then run the task again.  However, I am having all sort of problems doing this.  I am marking you correct cause you did answer the question.  I'll just need to have some other issues cleared up first.

Comment: oh well instead of the method detaching and reattaching the adapter. why dont you have it run the async task again, which postexecute is to repopulate list. Just have the method unattach any currrent adapters first. if theres anything else feel free to ask!

Comment: Hey thanks.. yeah, I was trying that method... but I was having issue accessing them from the `FragmentActivity`.  And when I did, certain things were crashing cause the `context` returned null.  Putting this on hold for a moment though.